# Classification of grouping algorithms

Tags: algorithm

I have a question about grouping algorithms. I need to do a task that uses at least three types of non-hierarchical clustering algorithms, and so far I've only found k-means. Anyone know what the others are and can be easily implemented in python?

Comment: The first Google hit for `cluster analysis python` is [10 Clustering Algorithms With Python](https://machinelearningmastery.com/clustering-algorithms-with-python/)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.